# repeatedly remove items from list in class-object (Python)

Tags: python, list, class, oop, methods

How can I remove items from a list repeatedly in Python 3? For the first item my code works, but if I try to apply the method that removes items again it produces a `TypeError`. Here is the code that I am working with:

## BlackJack Game

```
from random import choice

class Black_jack_deck(object):

    def __init__(self, full_deck=(([str(i) for i in range(2,11)]+["A","J","Q","K"])*4*6)): #a deck of 312 cards containing 6* 52 french cards
        self.full_deck = full_deck

    def draw(self, draw=True):
        self.draw = choice(self.full_deck)   #I use choice to simulate the dealer drawing a card from the top of a mixed card staple
        return self.draw
        self.full_deck = (self.full_deck).remove(self.draw)   


deck = Black_jack_deck()
```

The error that is produced when I try to call `deck.draw()` for a second time looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    deck.draw()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Note: even without the `choice()` function, for instance using `pop()` on a shuffled `full_deck`, the same error occurs.

Comment: Please post correctly formatted code. White-space is syntactically significant in Python, and as this stands it will not work.

Comment: You appear to have a function and a variable both named `self.draw`. How do you expect Python to know which one you mean?

Comment: Python "knows" which one it is: it's the last one that was set. You're *overwriting* one with the other.

Comment: @Morgoth done, now it looks like on my PC where it works

Comment: Why is full_deck an argument with a default value? And why not `num_decks = 6`, `self.full_deck = 'A23456789JQK' * 4 * num_decks` then `random.shuffle(self.full_deck)`?

Comment: Also, might be better to call it the "shoe".

Comment: @Harvey that makes sense, the way it was written is just a relict from when i had the full_deck list composed out of a few other lists incase i wanted to work with them seperatly. Thanks for the tipp with "shoe" i will change the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were overwriting the `Black_jack_deck.draw()` method with the card drawn. Hence the error about `deck.draw()` is a `'str' object` and `is not callable`.

Here's a shorter version. Do you need to remember the drawn card in the shoe? And I removed the boolean argument to `draw()` because I didn't know why it was there.

```
In [94]: class CardShoe(object):
    ...:     def __init__(self, num_decks=6):
    ...:         self.cards = list('A23456789JQK' * 4 * num_decks)
    ...:         random.shuffle(self.cards)
    ...:
    ...:     def draw(self):
    ...:         self.last_card_drawn = self.cards.pop()
    ...:         return self.last_card_drawn
    ...:

In [95]: shoe = CardShoe()

In [96]: shoe.draw()
Out[96]: '2'

In [97]: shoe.draw()
Out[97]: '8'
```

Comment: The thing with the memory will come in later. For now I was just trying to make the card drawing work. With the boolean argument I thought it was somehow necessary. Thanks for your answer, it helped me very much :-)